# How to show all qtips in cytoscape.js on button click

Tags: javascript, qtip, qtip2, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

Hi I'm trying to show all qtips I have in my cytoscape.js graph when a button is clicked. Some of my elements are hidden so I need to check that they have the 'show' class first before trying to display the qtip. Here is my code

```
 cy.$('node[type = "net"]').forEach(function( ele ) {
          if (ele.hasClass('show')) {
             console.log(ele.id());
             ele.qtip('toggle',true);
             // i have also tried ele.qtip('show');       
      }
      });
```

However I am getting the following error in my browser console.

'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined: cytoscape-qtip.js:268'

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you define your qtips in advance if you use the API.

The easiest way to toggle qtips on multiple elements is custom events.  Add something like `qtipshow` in your show event config string and use `eles.trigger('qtipshow').

You can use the same approach for hiding.

Make sure to config your qtips to show more than one at once: http://qtip2.com/options

I'm not sure what the issue is with your method using the API, since it doesn't have enough context to tell -- but events are easier to use anyway.

Comment: Thanks Max, I think I found the option to set to allow more than one qtip to show at once 'solo:false'. However I am struggling to understand how to add a custom event as you have described. Are you able to show me an example of a custom event like you are suggesting? I've built up a jsfiddle that I have started to work on. https://jsfiddle.net/snfrLbcq/6/  Apologies I'm still relatively new to javascript.

Comment: Hi Max, I think I worked out what you meant. However I cannot get the qtips to show still. The updated code is here. Could you please have a look for me? https://jsfiddle.net/snfrLbcq/17/

Comment: You made some basic mistakes with your objects and API calls.  Make sure to use a proper editor like Atom and a proper debugger like Chrome. https://jsfiddle.net/snfrLbcq/19/